# fluent UI Search component list issue

Tags: angular, fluent

Hi I am tring to use fluent in angular and create a search component but having issue with adding elements in list. I tried below without sucess

```
<fluent-search placeholder="search" list="ice" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice"> </fluent-search>
  <datalist id="ice">
    <option value="Chocolate"></option>
    <option value="Coconut"></option>
    <option value="Mint"></option>
    <option value="Strawberry"></option>
    <option value="Vanilla"></option>
  </datalist>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am tring to use in an Angular project fluent web components. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/. I tried to create a search box but did not managed to do this. Can someone help me with a sample? I added above the code that I tried.